# Web Push - Placing service worker

Tags: push-notification, push, service-worker, web-push

From here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

1. If the service worker is at the **root** of the domain, this means
   that the service worker's scope will be the entire origin.
2. But If we register the service worker file at /example/sw.js, then
   the service worker would only see **fetch** events for pages whose
   URL starts with /example/ (i.e. /example/page1/, /example/page2/).

Second point mentions only **fetch** won't work at / (root or other than **example**) if I place the service worker at /example/.

But subscription (generation of sub object) itself not getting generated if the service worker is at /example/ and if the web page is at / (root or other than **example**), which the doc clearly doesn't explain.

Please let me know, if even the generation of subscription (pushManager.getSubscription) in the service worker itself won't happen.

PS: I have tried it on Chrome 54.0.2840.100 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: In general, since it's web push, I would put the service worker in the root, following the style of the Notification API which has authorizations that refer to the domain and not the path.

Answer (score 1):

Generation of **subscription** object does not depend on service worker scope. You can do it any where

Eg.
permission.js

```js
export function allowNotifications(scope){
  if (navigator.serviceWorker && Notification){
    if( Notification.permission !== "granted") {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
        subscribe(reg);
      });
    }
  }
}

function subscribe(reg) {
     reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true}).then(function(pushSubscription) {
          bindUserToDevice(JSON.stringify(pushSubscription));
     }, function (err) {
        console.log('error');
      });
}

export function bindUserToDevice(subscriptionObj) {

  // received subsciption object should be send to backend to bind the device for pushes
  var data = {
    type: 'POST',
    url : '/bind',
    body: subscriptionObj,
  };
  fetch('/bind', data);

}
```

**allowNotifications** function can be called from anywhere. Only the service worker file should be present on root which should have **push** event

```js
 global.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    var pushObj = event.data.json();
    var pushData = pushObj.data;

    var title = pushData && pushData.title;
    var body = pushData && pushData.body;
    var icon = '/img/logo.png';

    event.waitUntil(global.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        data:pushData
    }));
});
```